# How to run SPARQL spatial query?

Tags: sparql, spatial, dbpedia

What is wrong with the following sparql spatial query?

```
    PREFIX spatial: <http://jena.apache.org/spatial#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?placeName
{
    ?place spatial:nearby (40.7128 74.0060 1000 'km') .
    ?place rdfs:label ?placeName
}
```

Coordinates inside are coordinates of New York and it is supposed to find places 1000 km of New York but dbpedia query is empty.

Comment: I don't understand why you think that DBpedia which is hosted on a Virtuoso triple store should "understand" an Apache Jena specific Geo predicate? Virtuoso has its own [geo-spatial support](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtGeoSPARQLEnhancementDocs)

Comment: Or did you load DBpedia dataset into a local Apache Jena based triple store like TDB?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query for the Virtuoso SPARQL Endpoint on DBpedia.

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?placeName WHERE
{
  dbr:New_York_City geo:geometry ?ny .
  ?place geo:geometry ?placeGeometry .
  ?place rdfs:label ?placeName .

  FILTER(bif:st_distance(?ny, ?placeGeometry) < 1000)
  FILTER (LANG(?placeName) = 'en')
}
```